# How to dismiss a snackbar when user click elsewhere in flutter?

Tags: flutter, snackbar

I am new to flutter so I am not able to find the solution of my problem. I hope to find solution here. When I am clicking back to back then all the snackbar are showing and I have to wait till the last snackbar, but I want only last clicked resulted snackbar should be shown

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code to hide snackbar :

`scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar(mySnackBar);`

Comment: is mySnackBar of last tapped ??

Comment: it's the logic by which you need to maintain, this code just shows you how to hide/close the snackbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a duration to your snackbar. In this way it will automatically get dismissed.

```
HomeScreen.scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(duration: const Duration(minutes: 5), content: Text(message)));
```

Comment: after setting duration it's not dismissing the snackbars that comes in between of first and last tapped